# Cannot create directory with tilde

Tags: bash, mkdir, tilde, tilde-expansion

Given this script

```
# cat foo.sh
echo $HOME
set -x
mkdir ~
```

I am getting this result

```
# ./foo.sh
/home/Steven Penny
++ mkdir ''
mkdir: cannot create directory `': No such file or directory
```

If I run `mkdir "$HOME"` I have no problem. I think the issue is the space in the path, but can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `/etc/passwd` file was missing.

To elaborate, even one this simple will work

```
Steven Penny::0:0::/home/Steven Penny
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your debug output

```
++ mkdir ''
```

looks like "~" in `mkdir ~` is expanding to nothing, thus causing mkdir to fail. As `mkdir $HOME` works fine it means you have enough space in the disk.

Can you check if `echo ~` is displaying your home directory.